# Jump animation using animation class

Tags: c#, animation, xna

I need a little help in my little 2D game I want to create in XNA. I had almost no knowledge of programming before I got interested in XNA and C#, so maybe my problem is simple, but I just can't figure it out.

So basically, I have a base class, and I created an additional class `Animation` for animating sprites. I implemented some methods so that when the player presses "right" it would change the animation's current texture and increment X by a number of xf; anyway, the main idea is that I'm using just one instance of my class (basically, one object of type animation which changes its texture and properties based on what key is pressed).

So, I had no problems making it run right or left. Works out pretty well. The big problem started when I wanted to implement the jump sprite. So I created the 6 frames necessary for the sprite, but to animate it I have virtually no idea how to do it.

The only thing it does right now is to loop through the frames of the sprite, but the position (both .X and .Y) remain the same. The thing is, I have a `Vector2` position which holds the animation's current position, and it's fine with running because I simply increment it. However, when it comes to jumping, I want it to increment .X, but the .Y should be decremented (thus going up) until frame number 3; after frame number 3, until the last frame, I want the .Y position to go down (thus fall) with the corresponding animations (erm, frames).

So, basically, I don't know how to modify the .X and .Y so that it would display the frames that I need in the time I need. I don't know if you really understood what I'm trying to say; basically when I press the "up" key, it loops through the frames but the position remains the same.

My idea was to use a reference to the actual `Vector2` position which holds the animation's current position and pass it to the method in the other `Animation.cs` class, namely the `PlayAnimJump`, and modify the position after each frame and return it to the actual `Game1.cs` by reference. Even if I would do that (though I fail to see what good it would be), it wouldn't be updating the position as it should. So, any ideas?

Here is the code for the `PlayAnimJump` method from the `Animation` class:

```
public void PlayAnimJump(GameTime gameTime)
{
   elapsed += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Seconds;
   sourceRect = new Rectangle(currentFrame * frameWidth, 0, frameWidth, frameHeight);
   currentFrame = 0;
   if (elapsed >= frameTime)
   {
      if (currentFrame <=3)
      {
         if (looping)
         {
            currentFrame++;
         }
      }
      else if (currentFrame > 3)
      {
         currentFrame++;
      }
      elapsed = 0;
   }   
}
```

The default constructor for that class:

```
public Animation(ContentManager Content,string asset,float frameSpeed, int numbOfFrames, bool looping,Vector2 positionIT)
{
   this.assetName = asset;
   this.frameTime = frameSpeed;
   this.numbOfFrames =  numbOfFrames;
   this.looping = looping;
   this.animation = Content.Load<Texture2D>(asset);
   frameWidth=(animation.Width / numbOfFrames);
   frameHeight=animation.Height;
   position = positionIT;
}
```

Here is the code (from the main) when the up key is pressed:

```
else if (up)
{
   check = animation1.GetAsset();
   if (check == "eright")
   {
      animation1.SetFrameSpeed(0.8f);
      animation1.SetNumbOfFrames(6);
      animation1.ChangeTexture(Content, "SarimCumVreJiorjica");
      animation1.PlayAnimJump(gameTime);
      /*position1.x +=2f;
      position1.Y -=2f;
      */
   }
```

So, I'm not sure how, but I'm supposed to change `position1` according to the frame that's displayed by the animation in that second. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

If your animation class had a reference to the object that you wanted to move (i.e the object holding the position field) then you could modify it within the animation class, within the PlayAnimJump method.

Or, to reduce coupling, you could just have PlayAnimJump return a variable indicating how far into the jump you are (maybe a percentage of the jump, from 0 to 1). Then, you could use the percentage outside to set the objects position. So, if the jump is halfway done, the return value would be 0.5f, which you could use in an equation to determine the players y position. An example equation would be:

```
float percent = animation1.PlayAnimJump(gameTime);
float y = Math.Sin(percent * Math.PI) * maxJumpHeight;
player.positon.y = y;
```

This uses a sine wave to determine the players height throughout the jump animation. You would just need to write the code that determines the percentage of the way through the jump (currentFrame) in the PlayAnimJump method and return it.

Answer (score 0):

Formula of the frуefall for Y coordinate is

```
y = g * t ^ 2 / 2 + v0 * t + y0
```

Characters jump from height y0 vith start velocity v0 by Y axis and gravity gradually slows down and starts to fall.
Calculate deltaY using following formula

```
deltaY = g * t ^ 2 / 2 + v0 * t
```

First show the frame on which the character is pushed off the ground, then the frame on which it rises until it reaches the peak of the jump. Once the sign change deltaY from + to - show how the character change pose for fall. Something like that.